# How to use angular syntax in kendo chart templates

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

when using angular syntax inside chart template it is getting displayed as normal string.

I'm trying to add value of `text`  to the kendo chart axis label. check this [Sample](http://dojo.telerik.com/OGAjA/11)

```
$scope.text = "hi";
$scope.valueAxisConfig = {
     labels: {
     template: '{{text}}#= kendo.toString(value, \'c0\') #'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all KendoUI templates support AngularJS expressions (for all I know atleast).

As a workaround you can change the `valueAxis.labels.template`, which can either be a `string` or a `function returning a string`.

You can achieve the desired behavior by using the latter one.

```
$scope.text = "hi";
$scope.valueAxisConfig = { 
    labels: { 
        template: function (item) {
            return $scope.text + ' ' + kendo.toString(item.value, 'c0');
        }
    } 
}
```

I've also updated your [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EHedI).